# Changing a forms font color from another form

Tags: c#, forms, colors, fonts

I have a form let's call it formMain that has a menu which opens another form called formColors.
Now when formColors opens it has radio buttons labeled with Colors i.e Red

How can I change the font color of formMain to whichever option I choose in formColors?

Answer (score 2):

Create an [`Event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkzf914z.aspx) in `formColors` and subscribe to it in `formMain` or as Hans Passant pointed out you could use a public property and the Forms [DialogResult Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult.aspx) this would be the preferred way to do it.

WinForm DialogResult Example

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 frm2;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm2 = new Form2();
        if (frm2.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            this.BackColor = frm2.formColor;

        frm2.Close();   
    }
}
```

**Form2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Color newColor;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public Color formColor
    {
        get { return this.newColor; }
        set { this.newColor = value; }
    }

    private void btnRed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        newColor = Color.Red;
    }

    private void btnBlue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        newColor = Color.Blue;
    }

    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
    } 

}
```

---

WinForm Event Example:

**Form1:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frm2.ColorEvent += new ColorEventHandler(frm2_ColorEvent);

    }

    void frm2_ColorEvent(object sender, ColorEventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackColor = e.formColor;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm2.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

**Form2:**

```
public delegate void ColorEventHandler(object sender, ColorEventArgs e); 
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public event ColorEventHandler ColorEvent;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ColorEventArgs newColor = new ColorEventArgs();
        newColor.formColor=Color.Red;
        ColorEvent(this, newColor);
    }


}
```

**ColorEventClass**

```
public class ColorEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private Color newColor;
    public Color formColor
    {
        get { return this.newColor; }

        set { this.newColor = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't correct, a dialog should have no effect when the user cancels it.

Comment: @HansPassant The dialog has no effect on the parent form when canceled, only when the button is clicked to raise the new event.

Comment: So if the user clicks the button, then cancels the dialog it is still changed.  This should not be an event, just a public property.  And if ShowDialog() returns DialogResult.Ok then use the property.

Comment: @HansPassant That would be easier, I will edit answer to show it, I was just trying to give a quick example of a custom event.